# Разделить столбец по заданному условию в pandas

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pandas

Коллеги, добрый день! Пытаюсь сделать корректные действия при разделении столбца по определенным условиям. Вроде сделал, но есть ряд "ошибок" и сам код выглядит не pandorable. Помогите исправить/подкорректировать

Дан следующий датафрейм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

необходимо сделать следующее: вытащить #инвойса (как пример 18-0-115593), тип операции (Реализация или Поступление или Корректировка или Скидки) и дату операции.

Цель получить примерно следующий финальный датафрейм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вроде сделал, но вместо Скидок у меня получается (ГК), и код скорее всего грамоздкий

```
           # читаем файл и создаем DF
            df_62 = pd.read_excel(open('Карточка счета.xls', 'rb'))

            df_62.columns = ['Date', 'Name of invoice', 'Debet',  'Credit', 'Saldo' ]
        # вытаскиваем из столбца Name of invoice номер инвойса и дату
        df_62['invoice_main'] = df_62['Name of invoice'].str.extract(r'(\d+[ \-]\d+[ \-]\d+)')

         df_62['invoice_date'] = df_62['Name of invoice'].str.extract(r'(\d{2}[ \.]\d{2}[ \.]\d{4})')

   # вытаскиваем тип операции(Реализация или корректировка или скидки или...)
    def get_str_split(string):
        new_list = string.split(' ')
        for word in new_list:
            if word == "скидки":
                return new_list[1:3]
            else:
                return new_list[0]
    df_62['Name of invoice'] = df_62['Name of invoice'].astype(str)

    df_62['type_prov'] = df_62['Name of invoice'].apply(get_str_split)

     # у меня вместо типа операции "скидки" вытащился (ГК)
```

Был бы крайне признателен как это можно сделать попроще и по pandorable :)

Comment: Ну так нужно посмотреть, что попадает в new_list.

Comment: ну туда попадет значение столбца df_62['Name of invoice']

Comment: Ну очевидно же, что если вы видите слово "скидки", а питон его не видит, то что-то пошло не так. Чтобы узнать, что именно, нужно вывести содержание списка и посмотреть.

Comment: @Pavel, можете выложить данные в более "user-friendly" виде? Например в виде CSV / Excel / вывод `print(df)` в __текстовом__ виде. Набивать данные с картинки не хочется...

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/Oelahil8eP3-vg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо делать цикл для проверки каждого слова, можно сразу проверить наличие слова в списке:

```
def get_str_split(string):
    new_list = string.split() # отдельно указывать пробел не нужно, он используется по умолчанию
    if "скидки" in new_list:
        return new_list[1:3]
    else:
        return new_list[0]
```